# React Native Shadow according to NEO-BRUTALISM

Tags: android, shadow, dropshadow

How to give shadow to box without blur effect, something like NEO-BRUTALISM style...[in this image you can see monday titled box and grocery titled box shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4rPY.jpg)

In react native, I try to shadowOpacity:1; and shadowRadius: 1;

Comment: If you found something let me know. I'm struggling with the same.

Comment: Nvm I'm trying to create a neo-brutlalism inspired libarary so far I have created a View component with minimal functionality. Here is the link: https://github.com/Perfecto-always/react-native-brutalism.git